# C++ Virtual Studio Hello World missing command?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Specs: Windows 10 Pro,Programm used: Visual Studio Code;MinGW Compiler.

Path set to C:\MinGW\bin.

Im just getting into C++ and i was trying my hello world script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

When i run the C++ code in Virtual Studios: (CTRl+ALT+N)

```
[Running] g++ "c:\Users\Myusername\Documents\First Project\helloworld.cpp" && ./a.out
```

I get this errormessage:
*'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

Comment: User: 'std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;' instead of printf.
Remove stdio.h, you don't need it. the void parameter is not adding any value neither.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation command is wrong.

> g++ path_to_your_cpp -o runnable_path

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cout << "Hello world!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o hello_world.exe
```

And execute with:

```
hello_world.exe
```

Comment: @AntonAlthoff - that `&& ./a.out` in your command line seems to be an attempt to automatically run the app after compiling if compilation succeeds. Try `g++ main.cpp -o hello_world.exe && hello_world` to get the same behaviour. P.S. the error you were getting is because, under Windows, `./a.out` means execute `.` passing it `/a.out` as a parameter. For an executable (or batch file) *nix's `./prog` becomes `.\prog` or just `prog` under Windows.